# Request undefined with Postman test

Tags: express, postman

I have just started learning Node.js and I want to insert a new user in a database. When I try to test the code with Postman I get req undefined. 
Here is my json in Postman:
[image: Here is my json in Postman]

```
//userController.js
router.post('/user/new', function (req, res) {
var newUser = {
    email: req.email,
    first_name: req.first_name,
    last_name: req.last_name,
    phonenumber: req.phonenumber,
    password: req.password
}
console.log(req.email)
User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: All the POST data is in `req.body` object. So for example instead of `req.email`, use `req.body.email`

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out soon after. Also I needed to add const bodyParser = require("body-parser"); app.use(bodyParser.json()); in app.js.